# Trouble installing/using Atom packages on offline PC

Tags: package, installation, offline, atom-editor

I'm currently in the process of setting up my workspace on my company machine and have chosen Atom as my text editor of choice. The computer is not connected to the internet, so I will have to "manually" install packages. I've been having difficulties installing packages via usb transfer. I've copied and extracted packages to my ~/.atom/packages

The package I'm attempting to use (atom-beautify) shows up on the packages tab on the top of the editor. It also shows up under [Settings] -> [Packages].

When attempting to use the beautify I get the error message "Failed to activate the atom-beautify package" ... Cannot find module 'event-kit'

Also using Windows 10. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem. There are some way to solve your problem.I did not used win10, I am on win7.Yet you can try.

1. Paste atom-beautify to C:\Users\User.atom\packages and change pacakage.json
2. atom-beautify needs a dependency named bluebird, if you can try to add this to atom.

It step 1 or step 2 failed then goes to step 2,

3. Connecting your pc to internet run this command from your terminal: apm install atom-beautify

Source: https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/879#issuecomment-218753674

Answer (score 0):

Safest bet with installing atom packages offline is to install it on another online PC and then copy all contents from your packages location to offline PC.